# C# ListView to List<string>

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a ListView with string items, and i am trying to get these items and store them in List container.

I need the reverse operation of this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "Item1", "item2", "item3"}; 
resultsList.ItemsSource = myList;
```

So my Question is How to Parse ListView with Items to List?

Comment: Well do you know that the source *is* a `List<string>`? If so, just use: `(List<string>) resultsList.ItemsSource`.

Comment: Yes its worked that way :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast it to `IEnumerable<string>`

```
List<string> myList = ((IEnumerable<string>)resultsList.ItemsSource).ToList();
```

Comment: @RosenKaradinev glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can cast and use `ToList` to create a list:

```
myList = resultsList.ItemsSource.Cast<string>().ToList();
```